# Current path in functions.php

Tags: wordpress, function, path

How can I get current path of my page?

I know how to do it on my template, but I need it on functions.php.
And it has to be before send_headers hook, because I´ll use this info to set a cookie.

I have tried using PHP but it shows path for functions.php...

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
echo "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']  . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the request path with something like this in your `functions.php` file:

```
function current_request_path(){
  return $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
}
```

If that doesn't work, you could always [set the cookie with JavaScript](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html) after the page loads. You can get the current URL with via JavaScript using `window.location.href`